# Sort an array of struct by a given member of the struct (quick sort)

Tags: c++, c, sorting, struct, quicksort

I have an array of coordinates (struct type vector), and i want to sort them first by the x coordinate, and later by the y coordinate. Instead of writing two separate quick sort functions, is there a way to pass the member (x or y) as a parameter, and sort it by that?

basically is there a type of variable for axis, that i can use such that t[i].axis would mean the x coordinate when axis is x, and the y coordinate when its y

my struct:

```
struct point {
    float x, y;
};
```

edit:
i worked around the problem by writing a compare function, that compares based on the axis, but if anyone has an answer my question, i would appreciate it :)

Comment: You can self answer your own question

Comment: You should clarify if this question is for a C or C++ program. Also your question is not clear enough. Do you want a single Quicksort function to sort the vector by each field where the field is a parameter ?

Comment: I'm using C++. And yes, i want one function to be able to sort the vector by either field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question. But if you want to select for which member of the struct you want to sort, then you can use the below very simple function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

struct Point {
    float x{};
    float y{};

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Point& p) {
        return os << "X: " << std::left << std::setw(6) << p.x << "  Y: " << std::setw(6) << p.y << "\n";
    }
};

inline void selectiveSort(std::vector<Point>& vp, float Point::* member) {
    std::sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), [&](const Point & p1, const Point & p2) { return p1.*member < p2.*member; });
}

int main(void) {
    // Define and initialise vector
    std::vector<Point> points{ {1.0,9.0},{2.0,8.0},{3.0,7.0},{4.0,6.0},{5.0,5.0},{6.0,4.0},{7.0,3.0},{8.0,2.0},{9.0,1.0} };

    // Sort by y and display result
    selectiveSort(points, &Point::y);
    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout)); std::cout << "\n";

    // Sort by x and display result
    selectiveSort(points, &Point::x);
    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout)); std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```